# how to simulate click on a file field in Extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have a file upload field in my ExtJS app.

```
    this.scanUpload = new Ext.form.field.File({
        name: "scan field",
        emptyText: 'select file',
        allowBlank: false,
        x: 20, y: 3,
        width: 690,
        buttonText: 'select...',

        regex: /^.*(\.tiff)|(\.jpg)|(\.jpeg)|(\.gif)|(\.jpe)|(\.tif)|(\.png)$/i,

        listeners: {
            focus: function(){
                this.button.el.dom.click();
            }
        }
    });
```

I need to have a popup window that allows user to choose a file not only when the user  clicks on a "select..." button, but also when a "select file" text area is clicked. Code above doesn't work and I'm just wondering if it is possible to add such a behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, clicking on text box will open up the file browse window.

You can check the fiddle here -
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/TDCx8/1/)

```
Ext.create("Ext.form.field.File", {
        name: "scan field",
        emptyText: 'select file',
        allowBlank: false,
        x: 20, y: 3,
        width: 200,
        buttonText: 'select...',
    renderTo: "fieldDiv",

        regex: /^.*(\.tiff)|(\.jpg)|(\.jpeg)|(\.gif)|(\.jpe)|(\.tif)|(\.png)$/i,


    });
```

Comment: You should probably use "Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {etc...." in this instance, instead of the new keyword.

Comment: As long as ext-all.js is included, I think it doesn't matter which one is used.

Comment: Absolutely right, but its generally preferred to use create (e.g.: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127671-Ext.create-vs-the-keyword-new), either way your answer works for the question :)

Comment: It's even working in 4.1.0. Could not check in 4.0.7 as JsFiddle doesn't provide that framework, but it should work in all the versions as it's such a basic feature!

Comment: None of the above adresses the actual question: How can you manually trigger the file-select-popup?

Comment: The question is asking for "having textbox of file field also clickable to open file-browse-popup."

Manually triggering the file browse popup is not allowed from javascript due to security constraints. User SHOULD click the file browse button to open it.